# creating stored procedure in mysql calculate profit from product table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

My following code show some error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BEGIN SET @v1:= (select sum( cost_price * current_stock) from
>   product)' at line 2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_profit
BEGIN
SET @v1:= (select sum( cost_price * current_stock) from product);
SET @v2:= (select sum( selling_price * current_stock) from product);
SELECT (@v2 - @v1);
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the () after the procedure name.  Also, you should set a delimiter:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_profit()
BEGIN
SET @v1:= (select sum( cost_price * current_stock) from product);
SET @v2:= (select sum( selling_price * current_stock) from product);
SELECT (@v2 - @v1);
END;
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it-

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_profit()
BEGIN
SET @v1= (select sum( cost_price * current_stock) from product);
SET @v2= (select sum( selling_price * current_stock) from product);
SELECT (@v2 - @v1);
END
DELIMITER ;
```